# Pandas groupby cumulative sum,mean,median based on the flag values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to calculate cumulative calculations (sum,mean,median,etc) based on the values of Indicator

It should do the calculations for all the false indicator and print it adjacent to the true.
then calculated value should reset and start from  true until true appears again for Indicator.

Input data frame

| Amount | Indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | False |
| 20 | False |
| 5 | True |
| 8 | False |
| 4 | False |
| 6 | True |

output would be

| Amount | Indicator | Sum | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | False |  |  |
| 20 | False |  |  |
| 5 | True | 30 | 15 |
| 8 | False |  |  |
| 4 | False |  |  |
| 6 | True | 17 | 5.6 |

I tried to use groupby with cumsum() using Indicator as group , but have not had any luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one go using only one groupby:

```
df[["Sum", "Mean"]] = np.NaN
df.loc[df.Indicator, ["Sum", "Mean"]] = (df.groupby(df.Indicator.cumsum())
                                         .agg({"Amount": ["sum", "mean"]})
                                         .shift(1).iloc[1:].values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `cumsum` of `Indicator` column as group key to get cumsum and size of `Amount` column

```py
m = df['Indicator'].cumsum()

df['Sum'] = df.groupby(m)['Amount'].cumsum().shift().where(df['Indicator'])
df['Mean'] = df['Sum'].shift(-1).div(df.groupby(m)['Amount'].transform('size')).shift()
```

```
print(df)

   Amount  Indicator   Sum       Mean
0      10      False   NaN        NaN
1      20      False   NaN        NaN
2       5       True  30.0  15.000000
3       8      False   NaN        NaN
4       4      False   NaN        NaN
5       6       True  17.0   5.666667
```